# Attribute styling not showing up on the app

Tags: skmaps, scoutstyleeditor

I'm styling the `lcn bike` attribute within StyleEditor and it is visible on the map. However, when rendering that style on the app, it is not being shown, like it has no style applied to it.

Note that in order to see this attributes I must enable the "BICYCLE ROUTES" button. Is there a switch like that one but in the SDK? I'm using version 2.5 in iOS with Online mode and Full detail level.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bicycle lanes have a special treatment so you need to make them visible at map settings level, not at style level:

```
self.mapView.settings.showBicycleLanes = TRUE;
```

For example, in the FrameworkIOSDemo.xcodeproj -> Navigation folder ->  NavigationUIViewController.m, add it inside: `(void)addMapView`,now all bike routes should be visible in the Car Navigation UI.

Here is my daystyle.json `lcn bike` configuration:

```
       {
            "id" : "6.10",
            "isattribute" : true,
            "line" : 
            {
                "fill" : 
                {
                    "color" : "ff05ed",
                    "width" : 0.30
                }
            }
        },
```

[image]